# SIP: Key.Shift not getting detected

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create a text box which accepts only alphabets and numbers, and discards all the special characters. I need this for entering a valid file name, without extension.
I am using the following code:

```
private void txtFName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(((e.Key >= Key.A) && (e.Key <= Key.Z)) || ((e.Key >= Key.D0) && (e.Key <= Key.D9)) || (e.Key == Key.Shift) || (e.Key == Key.Back)))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("No Special Characters are Allowed!");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the "KeyPress" event is not there, so I figured out that this is the best way to achieve what I am doing.

The problem I am facing is:

As you can see in the code above, I have taken care of the "Shift" key press, but when I press the "Shift" key on the SIP, the "No Special Characters are Allowed" Message box pops up 3 times before I can key in an upper case alphabet!!! So this essentially prevents me from entering any Upper case characters.

Worse still, it is accepting all the characters !@#$%^&*(). Probably because it is detecting these as numbers from 0-9. It looks that the key codes are being returned the same for 2 and @, 3 and # and so on. This is very strange behavior! And I can not even use the underscore key with the above technique.

Such behavior is obviously not acceptable in a professional App.

How can I create a text box which accepts only alphabets, numbers and underscore, and discards all other characters?
Also, is there a problem with the "Shift" key not getting detected?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query, you want to validate your text box.

I would use regular expressions to do this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// Add chars which you don't want the user to be able to enter
private Regex regularExpression = new Regex(@"!@#$%^&*().", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Your text changed event handler
private void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Replace the forbidden char with ""
    txtInput.Text = regularExpression.Replace(txtInput.Text, "");
    txtInput.SelectionStart = txtInput.Text.Length;
}
```

Hopefully this will work for you.